# Filtering Out Inappropriate Words from a Chatroom

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, chatroom

Basically, below I am posting a function that posts a chat in a chatroom (calling other functions of course). This works perfectly. However, my app got rejected by Apple due to the possibility of inappropriate content appearing in my chatroom. So, I decided to filter out inappropriate content by making an array of inappropriate words, iterating through that array using a for loop and search in the user's posted message (under the variable message) for an inappropriate word, and replacing that word with the amount of *** depending on the length of the words. Below is my code, but I am missing some stuff. Please tell me what code to add, or a better way to do this. Here is my code (NOTE: BLACKLIST IS MY ARRAY OF INAPPROPRIATE WORDS):

```
- (void)displayChatMessage:(NSString*)message fromUser:(NSString*)userName {


    int i=0;

    int goodJobRunCount = 0;

    for (i=0; i<[blackList count]; i++)

    {
        NSString *car = [blackList objectAtIndex:i];
        NSRange searchResult = [message rangeOfString:car];

        if (searchResult.location == NSNotFound) {

            goodJobRunCount=goodJobRunCount+1;

            if (goodJobRunCount >= i){

                message2= [NSString stringWithFormat:message];
            }


        } else{


            NSUInteger length= searchResult.length;

            int runLength = 0;

           message2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

            while (runLength < length){

                NSString *string2 = [message2 stringByAppendingFormat:
                                 @"*"];
                message2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:string2];


                runLength = runLength +1;

            }
        }



    }







      [chat appendTextAfterLinebreak:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", userName, message]];
       [chat scrollToBottom:chat];




    }
```

Comment: This could be a good candidate for the code review SE site.

Comment: I doubt that apple will allow your app for any audience even with a filter function. also how do you want to handle words like *A$$hole* or *3itch*

Comment: WhatsUp has no filtering and Apple allowed it -> Apple reviewers missed that out ? Also I see no filtering mechanism inside iMessenger 
WTF !?

Comment: We don't know enough of the app and about the internals of the review process. but for example all browsers are 17+, because they could access erotic content. I can imagine that if the app has public chat rooms it will be handled differently than private communication style apps like WhatsApp or iMessenger. I am only certain that telling apple "hey, I introduced some word based censorship" will not convince them, as I tried to show them that it will be to easy to beat. BTW: How will it deal with WTF or What the fukk?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you just run in loop something like

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < blacklist.count;i++)
{
    NSMutableString* stars = [NSMutableString alloc]init]; 

    NSRange searchResult = [message rangeOfString:(NSString*)[blackList objectAtIndex:
    if (searchResult.location == NSNotFound) 
         continue;//break or whatever is it in obj-c 
    for(int j = 0 ; j < (NSString*)[blackList objectAtIndex:i].length;j++)
          [stars appendString:@"*"];
    message = [message  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString*)[blackList objectAtIndex:i] withString:stars];
}
```

Comment: That solution is perfect, but how do I prevent it from starring out words like "classy", that has a "curse word" inside of it, but is not itself a curse word?

Comment: True!!didn't think about...
Well whatever solution I thinking about now is to make an array of words out of message , each word is a member of array .
and then to go through the array and check if the word is equal to some word in blacklist ... it is long solution but there is nothing else going on my mind atm .

Comment: bad thing it will have N*M complexity :(

Comment: actually now I thinking about another solution: after you do have a range of that string stored in searchResult you can make a simple check if it is a full word or not , check if the next character is ' ' /',' / '.' '/!'  also if the previous character is 1 of them -> then you can replace the string .

Comment: note:just make sure you are not violating the bounds of an array/string when you are checking.

Comment: using fast enumeration over blacklist would avoid using `objectAtIndex:` calls and casting.

Comment: it is called "*fast* enumeration" for a reason. also `objectAtIndex:` must be slower than just hoping to the next element. Also enumeration provided mutation guarding. If applicable enumeration is always to be preferred. if you also need object's index block based enumeration is preferred over fast enumeration, as the ides is provided by free, no expensive and possible faulty `indexForObject:` needed.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Thank you very much for the info -> I am quite new for Obj-C so don't get mad please --cheers and thanks for info :)

Comment: @vikingosegundo Thanks , could you please take a look on my question I got frustrated with a delegates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310786/obj-c-delegate-inside-delegate

Thanks in advance