# Obj-C Delegate inside Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have subclassed a view that I am using as header view it has some buttons delegate inside it and it works perfect .

However I am presenting a modalViewController above my viewController .
(in my modalViewController I have implemented the same header , and it does get the delegates from the header) but this view it self has to delegate to the previous viewController if the back button of the header is pressed.

I have made the same functions but my viewController never gets it's delegate... :(
I am quite new to Obj-C and I don't know maybe I am doing something illegal here.

here is the code of modalViewController trying to delegate to the previous viewController

```
#pragma mark - header delegate
- (void)header:(header *)header backbuttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(header == logo)
    {
        NSLog(@"gotBackButtonDelegate");
        //delete the items array
        //_itemSourceArray = nil;
        [delegate allEventsDrillPage:self backbuttonPressed:sender];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

This delegate does triggers from the header view.

however in my previous viewController:

```
- (void)allEventsDrillPage:(allEventsDrillPage *)allEventsDrillPage backbuttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender //doesn't work :(
{
    NSLog(@"got back delegate!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
//    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    _drillPage = nil;
}
```

never get called

I calling the  modalViewController like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [_allEventsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     [self->_allEventsTableView setNeedsDisplay];
     [self->_allEventsTableView reloadData];
     _drillPage = [[allEventsDrillPage alloc]initWithDictionary:((NSDictionary*)    [_tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])];
     _drillPage.delegate = self;
     [self presentViewController:_drillPage animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in its .h file I did

```
@interface allEvents : UIViewController <headerDelegate , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate ,allEventsDrillPageDelegate>
```

I don't get what am I missing here :-/ can some1 take a look please ?
if needed more info I will added just ask for it.

**EDIT:**

protocol of delegate inside the modalViewController

```
@class allEventsDrillPage;
@protocol allEventsDrillPageDelegate   //define delegate protocol
    - (void)allEventsDrillPage:(allEventsDrillPage*)allEventsDrillPage backbuttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender;
@end
@interface allEventsDrillPage : UIViewController
{    
   id<allEventsDrillPageDelegate> __weak delegate;
   ....
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <allEventsDrillPageDelegate> delegate; //define
```

Comment: Can you give code: protocol of delegate and how to declare this delegate in h file

Comment: of header or of the modalViewController?

Comment: How to declare this : [delegate allEventsDrillPage:self backbuttonPressed:sender];

Comment: Strange! Code is OK. Let try debug step into at : [delegate allEventsDrillPage:self backbuttonPressed:sender]; at see where did he go?

Comment: @nmh it works fine for you ? hmm for me the NSLog never get called :( , and when I set a break point to delegate I have assembly lines I don't understand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51493/discussion-between-nmh-and-roma-mt)

Comment: fist thing when it coms to delegate: did you set it? where do you create it? do you overwrite it?

Comment: @vikingosegundo yes I've set it to self , and inside self i put it's delegate protocol inside <>
you can see in the 3rd block of code when the tableView selected called

Comment: than the delegate must be deallocated in the meantime.

Comment: @vikingosegundo you mean to set it to nil ?(I am using ARC) 
could you please help me to determine where to dealocate it ? i mean when ?

Comment: ARC is just automatic reference counting — not magic. if you don't maintain ownership correctly it will be gone very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nmh's answer is correct. I wrote up an answer earlier but his came in faster, so I thought I would take out the other parts and just add the explanations here.

You have this:

```
@interface allEventsDrillPage : UIViewController
{    
   id<allEventsDrillPageDelegate> __weak delegate;
   ....
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <allEventsDrillPageDelegate> delegate;
```

With this `id<allEventsDrillPageDelegate> __weak delegate;` you declare an ivar.

With this `@property (weak, nonatomic) id <allEventsDrillPageDelegate> delegate;` you are declaring a property.

Since Xcode 4.4 you get auto-synthesization.
And so this line:

```
_drillPage.delegate = self;
```

You are setting the one via the property.

And not this:

```
id<allEventsDrillPageDelegate> __weak delegate;
```

So what you have here:

```
[delegate allEventsDrillPage:self backbuttonPressed:sender];
```

You are using the ivar above, not the one via the property.
And `delegate` is thus `nil.`

And so, if you try to send a message to the delegate using nmh's solution or:

```
[self.delegate allEventsDrillPage:self backbuttonPressed:sender];
```

It should work as expected.

***Addendum to dismissing modal view controller:***

Instead of dismissing it from the current view controller, dismiss it from the one who presented it, so:

```
- (void)header:(header *)header backbuttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(header == logo)
    {
        NSLog(@"gotBackButtonDelegate");
        [_delegate allEventsDrillPage:self backbuttonPressed:sender]; 
        //or self.delegate
    }
}
```

And in:

```
- (void)allEventsDrillPage:(allEventsDrillPage *)allEventsDrillPage backbuttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"got back delegate!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    _drillPage = nil;
}
```

Or even better:

```
- (void)allEventsDrillPage:(allEventsDrillPage *)allEventsDrillPage backbuttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
     NSLog(@"got back delegate!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
         _drillPage = nil;
     }];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for explonations :) thank you very much !  
I've accepted nmh's anwer it came earlier and helped to solve the problem , however I think your answer should be credited :) thank you very much ! -cheers

Comment: @Roma-MT His answer is correct and it's good to remain as accepted. I just wanted to add the explanations. Most welcome, not a problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
- (void)header:(header *)header backbuttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(header == logo)
    {
        NSLog(@"gotBackButtonDelegate");
        // delete the items array
        //_itemSourceArray = nil;

        // my comment: you should replace "delegate" to "_delegate" 
        // and it works.  I tested. It's OK. Wow.

        [_delegate allEventsDrillPage:self backbuttonPressed:sender];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```